# How to prevent ID Changing Expliot in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, security, entity-framework-core

When saving an entity in EntityFrameworkCore, the Id of course is posted as part of the update statement from the client.

In reading a blog, they mentioned that it is possible for a hacker to simply change the Id of an entity, and thereby cause an update for a different entity, possibly for a different user.

Is there a way to lock this down?

The only way I can think of is to get the existing entity on the server, and then confirm that it does indeed belong to the current user, and only then update.

Comment: Use a certificate infrastructure?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on that?  This is for data coming from a browser, so I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: We check that the user has access on POST. We use viewmodels to insure only certain fields can be changed. Then we fetch the entity and update those fields from the view model. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520780/how-secure-the-entityid-in-hidden-field-for-editing-form-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer does not really solve the issue,  as it lets people with access to still be malicious and alter records outside the scope of what is allowed within that edit/update event.

The security side is good practice, however in order to protect further, you would be better with GUID primary keys,  instead of 1, 2, 3   and then also a timestamp field for concurrency Checking.

For example,  Lets say we have a model called Person, we want to ensure that when this is updated, its not only out of date ( i.E  someone beat us to it )   but we want to also make sure this is the correct record, I.E  Concurrency:  Assuming SQL server here.

```
public class Person{
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

In our Fluent API Model Creating we would then configure the timestamp as a rowversion identifier.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .Property(p => p.Timestamp)
        .IsRowVersion();
}
```

Together with GUID key,  they not only got to work out a correct GUID,   but also have to get the rowversion right too.

Now what you dont want to do is try and resolve the concurrency, as advised all over the place,  because essentially, you managed to find another guid, and got a hit,  you now dont want to start copying data from one secure source to another.   Instead you can either redirect to your original get  ( this will re-check permissions and reload  ( with an unable to update message )  or you can simply say it failed.   Either way, you want to avoid saying  ( well done, that was a good guess at another GUID, but the timestamp is wrong ).   I.E   on login you wouldn't say password is wrong, you just say login failed.

It can be a pain in the rear for the end user, because you are not making things easy for them,  You are not handling the concurrency for them and matching up and sorting all the data for them.   But you have to remember easier for a user = easier for a bad user.  Just like its no longer easy to jump onto an airplane, it's not meant to piss you off, its meant to keep you safe,  and thats the rules.

Its worth thinking about the data as its own entity,   security of a system,  should not be the only way you secure the data, passwords are easy to crack, hashed passwords are easy to crack.   peoples computers are easy to crack, and then get forward access onto systems.   Thats just one part, You should be protecting the data, even from any God or admin role you may have implemented.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much.  I have accepted this as the answer.

Comment: Essentially, I am going to add a column called RowGuid, and then put the ConcurrencyCheck property on it.  So a hacker would have to guess the Id of the entity, plus the Guid of the entity to make a spurious update.

Comment: Your welcome, and yes that would work too.  Concurrency works really well

Comment: It's like an AntiForgery token on a row.

Comment: yep and if you really want to make it tough, you can checkout the row, to the user in a checkout table.   i.e  checkout{ id:'', userid:'', expires:'' }   and then check its checked out, and by that user :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is where an authorization framework comes in. The server side code takes the identity of the caller and checks if the caller is allowed to perform that action.

If your business rules say that users are only allowed to update their own entities, your authZ checks whether the id associated with the authenticated user matches the one in the update statement.

If the user has admin privileges, he/she is likely to be allowed to update any entity.